# NameError even though variable no longer exists

Tags: python, class

I am new to object oriented programming with Python. I have a class called Buffer, where I want to store items temporarily. Initially, I wanted to track the time an item spends in the buffer with a "time_in_buffer"-variable. I discarded the idea, but kept it as a comment so I would think of it later on.
Now, when I want to create a buffer object, I thought I would only need to call it with the variable buffer_slots, but I get: 'NameError: name 'time_in_buffer' is not defined'

I have the Buffer class in a seperate file and run the program in a main-file which is a jupyter notebook. I saved the Buffer file regularly and also hit the "Run Python File in Terminal"-Button and also ran the lines of code containing the import Buffer command whenever I made adjustments.

the class is the following

```
class Buffer:
    def __init__(self, buffer_slots: int):
        self.buffer_slots = buffer_slots
        self.items = []
        #time_in_buffer

    def add_item_to_buffer(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def get_items_in_buffer(self):
        return len(self.items)
```

and the relevant lines of code from the mainmethod are as such:

```
import Packer
from Bin import Bin
from Buffer import Buffer
import Item

from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
import math
import os
```

Sidenote: I also tried with a simple 'import Buffer', which also didn't work
The buffer is created as such:

```
buffer = Buffer.Buffer(buffer_slots = 5)
```

Sidesidenote:
Lastly I was wondering how I can actually add an item to the 'items' list, and thought it should be something like this:

```
buffer.add_item_to_buffer(someitem)
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Traceback errors give you the line where it was found, where does the error point to?

Comment: The Traceback error pointed to the line that says '#time_in_buffer'. Which is why I guessed that something was wrong with the import, I just could'nt figure out, what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be still trying to run a copy of the `Buffer.py` file. Verify that you are importing and running from the correct path where you have made the changes.

Regarding the code,

First things first. It is not a good idea to name files with names of packages or class names. I saved the `Buffer` class in a file named `buffer.py`

```
class Buffer:
def __init__(self, buffer_slots: int):
    self.buffer_slots = buffer_slots
    self.items = []
    #time_in_buffer

def add_item_to_buffer(self, item):
    self.items.append(item)

def get_items_in_buffer(self):
    return len(self.items)
```

Imported this file into the actual code:

```
from buffer import Buffer
```

The right way to create an object is as below:

```
buffer = Buffer(buffer_slots=5)
```

And finally, the whole program:

```
from buffer import Buffer

# creating object of the class
buffer = Buffer(buffer_slots = 5)

# adding an item to items 
someitem = "1"
buffer.add_item_to_buffer(someitem)

# getting the length
length_of_items = buffer.get_items_in_buffer()
print("Length of items: ", length_of_items)
# 1

# adding another item to items 
someitem = "2"
buffer.add_item_to_buffer(someitem)

# getting the length
length_of_items = buffer.get_items_in_buffer()
print("Length of items: ", length_of_items)
# 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help! It works!
So happy right now :)
How could I verify though, that I am importing and running from the correct path where I made the changes?